# Get a system from a array of expressions

Tags: functions, list-manipulation, system

I have an array of expresions like:

```
A = {x+y-5, x-y-1}
```

I need to set all expresions to zero (transforming each expression into a function) and turn it into a system. After that I want to solve this system for x and y. Can someone help me with that?

Comment: `Solve[A == {0, 0}, {x, y}]`?

Comment: `Solve[Thread[A == 0]]` works too. No need to specify the variables if you're solving for all of them.

Comment: Thank you a lot